# Best way to import data from DataGridView into Oracle 11g

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle11g

Hello everyone since I'm new to C# would like to ask you if there are better ways to import data from DataGridView into Oracle 11g.   Best with an example. Here is my current code and I use parameters. Because of my drivers I can't use AddWithValue. Thank you

```
private void Btn_SAVE_IN_DATABASE_VEUPEN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; i++) //Schleife für INSERT Befehl
    {

        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(***********************");
        con.Open();

        string sql = "INSERT INTO AFTERSALES.INPUT_BOARDLEVEL_REPAIR_VEUPEN (BLR_REPORT_DATE, MONTH_OF_REPAIR_END, PCB_COUNTER, MANUFACTURER, REPORTING_OUTBOUND_DATE,  EMPTY,  QTY)"
                   + "VALUES (:BLR_REPORT_DATE, :MONTH_OF_REPAIR_END, :PCB_COUNTER, :MANUFACTURER, :REPORTING_OUTBOUND_DATE, :EMPTY, :QTY)";

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":BLR_REPORT_DATE", Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":MONTH_OF_REPAIR_END", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":PCB_COUNTER", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":MANUFACTURER", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":REPORTING_OUTBOUND_DATE", Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":EMPTY", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":QTY", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: DataGridView is a UI control, not a data structrue. Instead of trying to read the grid cells, use the *actual* source - the actual DataTable or List used to populate the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my two cents:

1 - why would you read from the grid? have one of your collegues add a single new column in between the existing columns and your code will create garbage. read the values from underlying datasource

2 - why do you recreate the connection for every row? Create it once, open it once, insert 
    x-rows, close it once

3 - i'd likely perform the entire operation with a transaction